# Extjs variable in proxy api store using crud

Tags: php, javascript, url, extjs, crud

I would put a variable in my proxy api store (using crud) but it not work.

The api config is an object , could you use a variable in object in javascript ?

I use Sencha Architect and he format api...

Do you have a suggest ?

My base store :

```
Ext.define('ModuleGestion.store.Pays', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'ModuleGestion.model.Pays'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'ModuleGestion.model.Pays',
            storeId: 'StorePays',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: {
                    create: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=create',
                    read: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=read',
                    update: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=update',
                    destroy: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=destroy'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

My model with variable in api proxy

```
var Url = 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/';
var UrlPays = Url+'Pays.php';

Ext.define('ModuleGestion.store.Pays', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'ModuleGestion.model.Pays'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'ModuleGestion.model.Pays',
            storeId: 'StorePays',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: '{\r\n    create: UrlPays+'action=create',\r\n    read: UrlPays+'action=read',\r\n    update: UrlPays+'action=update',\r\n    destroy: UrlPays+'action=destroy'\r\n}',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UrlPays` anywhere in your file, since you declared it in the global scope (i.e. outside of any function).

That should work if you fix this line:

```
api: '{\r\n    create: UrlPays+'action=create',\r\n    read: UrlPays+'action=read',\r\n    update: UrlPays+'action=update',\r\n    destroy: UrlPays+'action=destroy'\r\n}',
```

like this:

```
api: {
    create: UrlPays + 'action=create',
    read: UrlPays + 'action=read',
    update: UrlPays + 'action=update',
    destroy: UrlPays + 'action=destroy'
},
```

See the difference in the syntax highlighter?

Comment: Sencha Architect format the class when i use a variable in... my code api is exactly your code

Comment: Ok, that explains it. I could not believe you hadn't seen that. That's an issue with Architect then. Unfortunately, I've no experience with it. It formats your code as soon as you type it, or at a later step (like code generation, I don't know)?